# (Java) Parsing a String into a 2D Array of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer, 2d

It's my first time posting here, so please be gentle.

I've been given a plain text file that has an accumulation of numbers on different lines. (10x10 grid)

```
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

I've managed to load it into my Java application and print it out using..

```
System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

This prints out the file to the command line with no issues.

But I can't seem to parse it through as a integer in a 2D array?

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9....]
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Showing rest of your code will help others to help you.

Comment: When you say "I can't seem to parse it", what exactly is the issue you are facing?  Is there some code, error messages or stacktraces you could show us?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789\n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789 \n 0123456789\n0123456789\n0123456789");
        String str[]= stringBuffer.toString().split("\n");
        int[][] arr = new int[str.length][];

        for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            String currentLine=str[i].trim();
            int[] temp = new int[currentLine.length()];         
            for(int j=0;j<currentLine.length();j++){
                temp[j] =  Character.getNumericValue(currentLine.charAt(j));
            }
            arr[i]=temp;

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this method, and I seem to be getting garbage in terms of output.

Comment: arr[i] contains 2D int array of the given string... Not sure what you are referring to as garbage

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.toCharArray()` method:

```
// after reading a line into 'numString'

char [] charList = numString.toCharArray();
int [] intList = new int [charList.length];

for(int i = 0; i < intList.length; i++) {
    intList[i] = charList[i] - '0';

// now you have the ints from the line into intList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[][] to2D(String value) {
    String[] linesArray = value.split("\n");
    int[][] array2d = new int[linesArray.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
        char[] lineArray = linesArray[i].toCharArray();
        int[] array1d = new int[lineArray.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < lineArray.length; j++) {
            array1d[j] = Character.getNumericValue(lineArray[j]);
        }
        array2d[i] = array1d; 
    }   
    return array2d;
}
```

I prefer to work with Collections though (ArrayList in that case):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to2DList(String value) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList2d = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    String[] lines = value.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList1d = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (char digit : line.toCharArray()) {
            arrayList1d.add(Character.getNumericValue(digit));
        }
        arrayList2d.add(arrayList1d);
    }   
    return arrayList2d;
}
```